# on special Kähler manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, lie-algebras, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Take Lie group $G$ with some hypotheses
(compact, connected, semi-simple); call $T$ its maximal torus,
its Lie algebra $\operatorname{Lie}(G)=\mathbf g$,
its Cartan subalgebra $\operatorname{Lie}(T)=\mathbf t \subset \mathbf g$
and its Weyl group $W=N(T)/T$.

Why does the complexified space of conjugacy classes in $\mathbf g$
$$\mathcal M=(\mathbf t \otimes \mathbf C)/W$$
give a special Kähler manifold $\mathcal M$, if this is true?

Comment: Does it even give a manifold?  In general, since the Weyl group is finite, you may assume it acts on $t\otimes \mathbb{C}$ isometrically.  In particular, if $S^n$ is the unit sphere in $t\otimes \mathbb{C}$, then $\mathcal{M}$ is homeomorphic to the cone over $S^n/W$.  But a cone over a manifold is a manifold iff the manifold is a sphere, so we need $S^n/W$ to be homeomorphic to a sphere.  This seems unlikely to be true, in general...